# Google sheet, Is their a way to use "sparkline" formula for vertical data?

Tags: google-sheets

I never been even saw the "sparkline" formula since today.

When I have some data on column A2:A, could it be a way use "sparkline" formula for those? without rearrange the data horizontally on other cells but only by putting some formula on cell "A1"?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I didn't meant to answer my own question but, I could do by putting {"charttype","column"} at the end of the sheet. I just found right after post this question.

on A1

```
=sparkline(A2:A,{"charttype","column"})
```

I thought it could be advance or hidden tips to manage as I couldn't find a way by search on google. however, It's the way and glad to find new cool function today for me.